# Error trying to create a List of Object - Index out of Range (Google.APIs.Sheets.v4.Data.ValueRange)

Tags: .net, vb.net, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-sheets-api

I am having trouble wrapping my head arround these nested lists.

For the Google Sheets API to insert data I have to pass a List of Lists from what I understand that repersents the rows and columns.

How ever I cannot figure out how to load the values in the list.

```
        Dim requestBody As New ValueRange()

        Dim rowCount As Integer = 2

        requestBody.Values = New List(Of IList(Of Object))() From {New List(Of Object)()}

        requestBody.Values(0).Add(1)
        requestBody.Values(0).Add(2)
        requestBody.Values(0).Add(3)
        requestBody.Values(0).Add(4)
        requestBody.Values(0).Add(5)
        requestBody.Values(1).Add("a")
        requestBody.Values(1).Add("b")
        requestBody.Values(1).Add("c")
        requestBody.Values(1).Add("d")
        requestBody.Values(1).Add("e")
```

When ever I get to the second value (row), I am getting an error: Index out of Range.

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.'
```

Thanks for any help.

PS If anyone can share an example of converting a DataTable into this object (list of lists), then It would be much easier then looping through the rows and building this object manually and would be eternally grateful.

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append

UPDATE: This is the full code for the function I am trying to create.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Services
Imports Google.Apis.Sheets.v4
Imports Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data

Namespace Settings
    Public Class SettingsPage
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
        Dim _connstring As String

        Dim googleSecretJsonFilePath = Server.MapPath("GoogleSecret\GoogleSecret.json")
        Dim applicationName = "OPT Web Services"
        Dim scopes As String() = {SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets, SheetsService.Scope.Drive, SheetsService.Scope.DriveFile}
        Dim googleService = New GoogleService(googleSecretJsonFilePath, applicationName, scopes)
        Dim spreadSheetId = "14N-1R##########################sCWA7U" 'Private Live Sheet

        Protected Sub btnSendVersions_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSendVersions.Click
            'TODO: Append KS_SedonaSync_Version to Google Docs - Tab
            'TODO: Append SS_Version to Google Docs

            Dim range = "'Customer OPT Versions'!A:E"
            'A (0)  - OPT_Customer_Number
            'B (1)  - Version_Id
            'C (2)  - Date_Installed
            'D (3)  - SedonaSync_Event_Id
            'E (4)  - Version

            Dim ds As DataSet = Master.OPTWebConfig.GetVersionList(_connstring)

            Dim sheetService = googleService.GetSheetsService()

            Dim valueInputOption As SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.RAW
            Dim insertDataOption As SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.InsertDataOptionEnum = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.InsertDataOptionEnum.INSERTROWS

            Dim requestBody As New ValueRange()

            'Update OPT Version Numbers
            Dim rowCount As Integer = ds.Tables("Versions").Rows.Count
            'TODO: Make this work: requestBody.Values = ds.Tables("Versions").Rows

            'Test Adding Multiple Rows, May need to loop through DataTable rows if we cannot find a way to convert the DataTable.
            requestBody.Values = New List(Of IList(Of Object))() From {New List(Of Object)()}
            requestBody.Values(0).Add(1)
            requestBody.Values(0).Add(2)
            requestBody.Values(0).Add(3)
            requestBody.Values(0).Add(4)
            requestBody.Values(0).Add(5)
            requestBody.Values(1).Add("a")
            requestBody.Values(1).Add("b")
            requestBody.Values(1).Add("c")
            requestBody.Values(1).Add("d")
            requestBody.Values(1).Add("e")

            Dim request As SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest = sheetService.Spreadsheets.Values.Append(requestBody, spreadSheetId, range)
            request.ValueInputOption = valueInputOption
            request.InsertDataOption = insertDataOption
            Dim response = request.Execute()

            'TODO: Mark Rows in ds.Tables("Versions") as Sent_To_OPT = "Y" if Response is 200:OK
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Class GoogleService
        Private ReadOnly _googleSecretJsonFilePath As String
        Private ReadOnly _applicationName As String
        Private ReadOnly _scopes As String()
        Public Sub New(googleSecretJsonFilePath As String, applicationName As String, scopes As String())
            _googleSecretJsonFilePath = googleSecretJsonFilePath
            _applicationName = applicationName
            _scopes = scopes
        End Sub
        Public Function GetGoogleCredential() As GoogleCredential
            Dim credential As GoogleCredential
            Using stream = New FileStream(_googleSecretJsonFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
                credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(_scopes)
            End Using
            Return credential
        End Function
        Public Function GetSheetsService() As SheetsService
            Dim credential = GetGoogleCredential()
            Dim Base As New BaseClientService.Initializer
            Base.HttpClientInitializer = credential
            Base.ApplicationName = _applicationName
            Dim sheetsService = New SheetsService(Base)
            Return sheetsService
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats is wrong is kind of easy to see with the debugger.  I dont have access to that API, so the following just uses a `List(Of List(Of Object))` which is where the issue is:  After this line of code:

```
Dim requestBody As New List(Of IList(Of Object)) From {New List(Of Object)()}
```

The debugger shows:

[image]

So there is only one "row" in the `requestBody.Values` collection (which was added as a result of the `From {New List(Of Object)()`.  No other row is ever added.

```
' create collection, add row(0)
Dim Values As New List(Of IList(Of Object)) From {New List(Of Object)()}

Dim rowCount As Integer = 2

Values(0).Add(1)
Values(0).Add(2)
...

' add row(1)
Values.Add(New List(Of Object))
Values(1).Add("a")
Values(1).Add("b")
...
```

With such things, my preference would be to do everything the same and elide the `From...` initializer and add all rows the same way so it is easy what is going on.  The errant, unused `rowCount` makes it seem like this is a loop so doing them all the same would make that easier as well.  Results:

[image]

Comment: Ok i have to admit that i had no idea what i was doing with the From statement.  Your example makes so much more sense.  Now i can at least understand whats going on.  Works like a charm.

Comment: And you are correct the rowCount was setup for a loop to load the rows.  However i already have the rows in a DataTable object.  Could I be so bold to ask if you have any ideas on how to transfer the DataTable to the Values object without going through a loop?

Comment: You could use some linq to select one thing then the other.  There is still a loop, just not one you have to write.

Comment: Would there be a performance increase in using a linq over the method listed below?  I have to load about 1000 rows at a time.

Comment: 1000 rows shouldnt matter.  Linq can be more efficient with hundreds of thousands of items since execution can be deferred.

Comment: `Dim nums = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(k) k.Field(Of Int32)("Num")).ToArray()` (where "Num" is the integer column name) would at least allow you to avoid fishing the data out of the DT and perhaps casting it.  Adding to the Google object is different because *it seems* the DT columns become rows in it

Answer (score 0):

Is there a cleaner option then?

```
        Dim rowCount As Integer = ds.Tables("Versions").Rows.Count
        requestBody.Values = New List(Of IList(Of Object))()
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables("Versions").Rows
            requestBody.Values.Add(New List(Of Object))
            requestBody.Values(i).Add(row.Item(0))
            requestBody.Values(i).Add(row.Item(1))
            requestBody.Values(i).Add(row.Item(2))
            requestBody.Values(i).Add(row.Item(3))
            requestBody.Values(i).Add(row.Item(4))
            i = i + 1
        Next
```

Comment: This is really a different question not an answer to the original post.  SO frowns on questions morphing into new questions because it makes the unrelated/new question hard to answer and hard for others to search on

Comment: Understood.  Ok thanks I will post in new Thread.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

'OBTIENE EL ID DEL ARCHIVO REGISTRO EN INTERNET ID()

```
    ' If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
    ' at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json
    Dim Scopes As String = SheetsService.Scope.SpreadsheetsReadonly
    Dim ApplicationName As String = "Google Sheets API .NET Quickstart"

    Dim credential2 As UserCredential
    Dim stream2 = New FileStream(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + "\client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Dim credPath As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + "\"
    credential2 = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream2).Secrets, {Scopes}, "user", CancellationToken.None, New FileDataStore(credPath, True)).Result
    stream2.Close()

    ' Create Google Sheets API service.
    Dim Service = New SheetsService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {.HttpClientInitializer = credential2, .ApplicationName = ApplicationName})

    Dim ranges As IList
    Dim includeGridData As Boolean = False
    Dim request2 As SpreadsheetsResource.GetRequest = Service.Spreadsheets.Get(IDREGISTRO)
    request2.Ranges = ranges
    request2.IncludeGridData = includeGridData

    'TODOS LOS DATOS
    Dim response As Data.Spreadsheet = request2.Execute()
    Dim totalrows = response.Sheets(0).Properties.GridProperties.RowCount
    Dim totalcolumsn = response.Sheets(0).Properties.GridProperties.ColumnCount
    Dim Hoja = response.Sheets(0).Properties.Title
    Dim Range As String = Hoja + "!A2:" + "L" + totalrows.ToString

    ' Define request parameters.
    Dim request As SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest = Service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(IDREGISTRO, Range)
    Dim response2 As ValueRange = request.Execute()
    Dim values = response2.Values
    ' The ID of the spreadsheet to add row.
    Dim spreadsheetId As String = IDREGISTRO


    Dim r1 As String = Hoja & "!A" & totalrows & ":L" & totalrows

    ' Define one row
    Dim values2 As List(Of IList(Of Object)) = New List(Of IList(Of Object))()
    Dim obj As IList(Of Object) = New List(Of Object)()
    obj.Add(dt)
    obj.Add(TextBox1.Text)
    obj.Add(TextBox2.Text)
    obj.Add(TextBox6.Text)
    obj.Add(TextBox7.Text)
    obj.Add(TextBox3.Text)
    obj.Add(TextBox5.Text)
    obj.Add(TextBox4.Text)
    obj.Add(combobox1.Text)
    obj.Add(DIRMAC)
    obj.Add("NO")
    obj.Add(My.Application.Info.AssemblyName)
    values2.Add(obj)

    Dim valueInputOption As SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.RAW
    Dim insertDataOption As SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.InsertDataOptionEnum = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.InsertDataOptionEnum.INSERTROWS
    Dim request4 As SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest = Service.Spreadsheets.Values.Append(New ValueRange With {.Values = values2}, spreadsheetId, r1)
    request4.ValueInputOption = valueInputOption
    request4.InsertDataOption = insertDataOption
    Dim response4 = request4.Execute()
```